# Filtering Envelopes based on a type

Tags: docusignapi

I have a situation where I want to be able to differentiate between envelopes based on a 'type'. For example, I'll have quotes and invoices, both of these can be sent to the same person so I'd like to know if there's a way of checking some sort of field that could differentiate the two. Currently I'm rather crudely post processing the API results and checking for 'quote' in the document type and I'd like a rather more reliable solution

thanks, 
Oliver

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please be sure to check/accept the best answer to your questions! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Envelope Custom Fields](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeCustomFields/) aka [Document labels](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-document-labels) to specify additional metadata for an envelope.

> Envelope Custom fields aka Document labels can be used in the envelopes for your account to record information about the envelope, help search for envelopes and track information.  The envelope custom fields are not seen by the envelope recipients.

---

The **DocuSign [Web](https://demo.docusign.net/) sending tool** refers to the Envelope Custom fields as Document Labels. You can configure Document Labels as an Administrator on the Account. See instructions [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-document-labels)

Once the Document labels are configured at the account level, you can provide label values for each envelope you send through the web sending tool. See instructions [here](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-add-labels)

---

The other option is to specify Envelope Custom fields using the API.  Here is a sample [createEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) api request that specifies custom Fields associated with the envelope

```
{
    "emailSubject": "Envelope with custom fields",
    "status": "sent",
    "customFields": {
        "listCustomFields": [
            {
                "listItems": [
                    "sample string 1"
                ],
                "name": "myListField",
                "required": "true",
                "show": "true",
                "value": "MyListValue"
            }
        ],
        "textCustomFields": [
            {
                "name": "MyOwnTextField",
                "required": "true",
                "show": "true",
                "value": "MyValue"
            }
        ]
    },
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "recipientId": 1,
                "email": "kaysmith@acme.com",
                "name": "kay smith",
                "routingOrder": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "name": "Agreement",
            "fileExtension": "txt",
            "documentBase64": "RG9jIFRXTyBUV08gVFdP"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More good news: the DocuSign Sending web tool automatically enables the sender, from the web tool, to set the Envelope Custom Fields.

So if you are sending envelopes programmatically or your users are sending them, it is easy to set custom field values.

Comment: Hi are there instructions on how to do this from the web tool as I can't see the option in the sandbox

Comment: @Oliverb updated my answer to use the web sending tool for specifying Envelope Custom Fields (aka Document Labels)