# How to pass a "request id" to the signature request and retrieve it?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm looking to use the DocuSign REST Java API to request a signature from a template, but I'd like to include a specified request id string that I can retrieve via the envelope after the signer completes the form.

Envelope.setTransactionId("") sounded like what I wanted (though I'd rather have something permanent instead of just valid for 7 days as mentioned in the docs), so as an example I called:
envDef.setTransactionId("TRANS12345");

But when I sign the test Envelope and then query it with getEnvelope(...) and call getTransactionId() I get null.

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to properly retrieve the transaction ID, or if there is a better way of adding a permanent specified ID to a signing request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Envelope Custom Fields](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeCustomFields/) aka [Document labels](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-admin-guide-document-labels) to specify additional metadata for an envelope.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43638084/1219543) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, took me a while to get this working.  One piece of critical information I missed was that you have to define the custom fields/document labels in advance via the admin API before you can use them.